# h5f.create_dataset causes MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy, memory, h5py

I currently trying to store a big numpy.ndarray using [`h5py`](http://www.h5py.org/).

```
    print len(train_input_data_interweawed_normalized)
    print train_input_data_interweawed_normalized[0].shape
    raw_input("Something")
    print "Storing Train input"
    h5f = h5py.File(fbank+'train_input_'+str(dim)+'_'+str(total_frames_with_deltas)+'_window_height_'+str(window_height)+'.h5', 'w')
    h5f.create_dataset('train_input', data=np.concatenate(train_input_data_interweawed_normalized,axis=1))
    ##Program chrash here
    h5f.close()
```

output of print:

```
4834302
(45, 1, 8, 3)
```

But somehow the program chrashses with the error message MemoryError..

What does it mean?..  not enough ram? 
The ram usage according to htop is before it chrashes is 11 gb / 15 gb.

So it could not be that?

so what else?

Comment: Test the `np.concatenate()` step outside of the `h5f` call.  It has to create that big array before writing it to the file.  And while you are at it, show us the results of those print statements.   Yes, memory error usually means you are trying to create an array that is too large for your memory.  `htop` memory measurements are only part of the story.  We need some idea of how big that array is supposed to be.

Comment: yes.. it seems like `np.concatenate()` is causing the problem.. is it somehow possible to concatenate and save in steps?

Comment: It looks like `train_input_data_interweawed_normalized` is a very long list of relatively small arrays (1080 elements).  And the `concatenate` is trying to make a (45, 4834302, 8, 3) 4d array, 5G element array.  No wonder it's giving a memory error.  It may have enough space to hold those elements scattered around, but it can't put it all in one contiguous memory block.

Comment: See the docs about chunked storage, and reading/writing slices.  It might also be better if you rearranged the data so the concatenation, or its substitute occurred on the first dimension, e.g (40...., 45, 8, 3) array.  I haven't worked with big arrays and files like that, so can't speak from experience.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation process needs additionally at least the size of all list elements togehter as a continous memory block. If you only have 16GB of Ram the memory allocation is likely to fail.

Concatenating the data and then saving it to a HDF5-File doesn't make any sense here. Why do you put the data in a list of arrays?

The following example shows how to write the list contents without concatination or memory copy to a HDF5-Dataset of your desired size.

```
#get the dimensions
dim_1=len(train_input_data_interweawed_normalized)
dim_2=train_input_data_interweawed_normalized[0].shape

h5f=h5py.File(fbank+'train_input_'+str(dim)+'_'+str(total_frames_with_deltas)+'_window_height_'+str(window_height)+'.h5','w')
# create the dataset (change the datatype if your images have some other type)
#You have to adapt the chunk size to your needs (How do you want to read the data?)
dset_out = f_out.create_dataset('train_input', (dim_2[0],dim_1,dim_2[2],dim_2[3]), chunks=(dim_2[0], 100, dim_2[2], dim_2[3]),dtype='float32')
for i in range(0,dim_1):    
    dset_out[:,i:i+1,:,:]=train_input_data_interweawed_normalized[i]
f_out.close()
```